# How do I put a physical space (not styling) between <li> elements and <span> tags in IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-lists

We're starting to run some automated testing to speed up cross-browser testing. However we're running into issues because IE treats li elements different than other browsers. I'm not talking about the padding between the bullet point and the text, I'm talking about the actual text itself.

When the automated test runs, it copies the text from the browser and compares this text to the copied text from other browsers to detect any differences. However, IE is giving me issues. Instead of using an li tag, I'm using "bullet" so I don't have to deal with the formatting coming from Stack Overflow. So after copy/pasting the text from the browser into a text editor, this is what I see.

IE:

"bullet"Sample Text

Chrome:

"bullet" Sample Text

Again, I'm not talking about the actual styling between the browsers, they look identical with the same padding and css. It's ONLY the text that is copied from the browser that is different. This is failing the cross-browser tests because the two texts don't match.

Is there any way to force these to match?

Comment: the copy command should include white space for screen readers and desktop editors like notepad, otherwise the text would be on one line, screen readers would not be able to punctuate the text content. You could write your own copy method to loop through the selected elements and concat the textContent to serialize the text, without the added whitespace. Try turning on the Accessibility features in your chromium browser.

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the reply. It seems like it is working properly in Chrome, but in IE it is not including the white space. I would be checking for the Accessibility settings in IE then correct? This is all running on a build machine so I would have to look deeper into that. Is there no way to fix this in the code itself?

Comment: We would need a reproduction url  to debug the style rules for you. does your page for example contain pre or code elements? You could use the f12 console to output the textContent instead of copy commands. eg. document.querySelector('section').textContent